# generics - How to pass a lambda expression into a method?

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, generics, moq

I have a number of business service classes that I'm setting up unit tests for.

In mocking the data, I've got a fairly generic set of methods. One to provide a mocked dbSet, one to provide a service.

One thing I haven't managed to make generic as yet is the process of mocking the data context.

Right now I have something like:

```
mockDbSet = MyHelper.GetMockedDbSet(myData); // myData is an IQueryable List <T>
mockContext = new Mock<MyDataContext>();
// A handful of general .Setup lines snipped here
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Person).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
```

Every unit test fixture is the same except for the last line, which the

```
m => m.Person
```

is substituted for some other entity.

All entities share the same base classes.

What I'm after is something like this:

```
mockContext = MyHelper.GetMockedDbContext(m => m.Person);
```

and be able to put all this generic code into the helper class.

I can't work out how to implement `GetMockedDbContext`, though.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public static Mock<MyDataContext> GetMockedDbContext(Func<MyDataContext, object> func)
{
    var context = new Mock<MyDataContext>();

    // Now what?

    return context;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here's what I've ended up doing so far. Something like this was posted as an answer, and then deleted. It seems to work.

```
public static Mock<MyDataContext> GetMockedDbContext<TResult>(Expression<Func<MyDataContext, TResult>> func, TResult result)
{
    var context = new Mock<MyDataContext>();
    // Snipped out stuff
    context.Setup(func).Returns(result);
    return context;
}
```

Comment: How is `Setup` method on `Mock<T>` defined?

Comment: public ISetup<T, TResult> Setup<TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)

Comment: yep: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Setup - just copy the stuff including the `Expression` into your `GetMockDbContext` and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method's parameter should be of the same type as `Setup` method's parameter is, which means your method has to be generic too:

```
public static Mock<MyDataContext> GetMockedDbContext<T>(Expression<Func<MyDataContext, T>> func)
{
    var context = new Mock<MyDataContext>();

    // Now what?
    context.Setup(func).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);

    return context;
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I've posted above, so I'll mark it as an answer. My code updated above in the original question passes in the dbSet object.